# Определить, каких чисел в последовательности больше

Tags: python

Дана последовательность из n целых чисел. Определить, каких чисел в этой последовательности больше: положительных или отрицательных.

С клавиатуры вводится целое число n.

После n вводятся элементы последовательности - целые числа (каждое в отдельной строке).

Выводимым результатом работы программы является одна из 3-х строк:

POSITIVE - если положительных чисел больше;

NEGATIVE - если отрицательных чисел больше;

EQUALS - если положительных и отрицательных чисел равное количество.

```
for я уже использовал: 
negs = 0
pos = 0 
for i in map(int, input().split()):
 if i < 0: negs += 1 
 elif i > 0: pos += 1 
print("POSITIVE" if pos > negs 
else "NEGATIVE" if negs > pos 
else "EQUALS")
```

а надо while

Comment: *что с этим делать* Ну вполне очевидно, что писать программу. Заодно выяснить, как интерпретировать плюс ноль и минус ноль...

Comment: Ну, судя по заданию, вам нужно написать программу на языке Питон. Прямо вот идёте по шагам, у вас всё хорошо довольно расписано, просто берёте и программируете каждое действие. Действия причём тут типовые довольно, в любом таториале по Питону они расписаны подробно.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Вот такое решение подойдет?

```
pos = 0
neg = 0
for i in range(int(input())):
    x = int(input())
    if x<0:
        neg += 1
    elif x>0:
        pos += 1

if pos>neg:
    print('POSITIVE')
elif neg>pos:
    print('NEGATIVE')
else:
    print('EQUALS')
```

Вот вариант через `while`:

```
pos = 0
neg = 0
nums = int(input())
while nums > 0:
    x = int(input())
    if x<0:
        neg += 1
    elif x>0:
        pos += 1
    nums -= 1
    
if pos>neg:
    print('POSITIVE')
elif neg>pos:
    print('NEGATIVE')
else:
    print('EQUALS')
```

Comment: `0` - это положительное? `-0` - тоже?

Comment: нужно использовать цикл while

Comment: for я уже использовал: 
negs = 0
pos = 0
for i in map(int, input().split()):
    if i < 0:
        negs += 1
    elif i > 0:
        pos += 1
print("POSITIVE" if pos > negs else "NEGATIVE" if negs > pos else "EQUALS")

Comment: И вообще, проще суммировать `numpy.sign()`.

Comment: @Akina ну 0 вроде считается неотрецательным в математике, 0 и -0 равны и по условию в коде будут считаться положительными

Comment: *0 вроде считается неотрецательным в математике* Ну положительным он тоже не очень-то считается... не?

Comment: @Антон а чего в условии не написали, что обязательно через while делть?)

Comment: @Akina он не является ни положительным, ни отрицательным) В общем тут все зависит от условий конкретной задачи, в условии ничего не сказано про 0 и что с ним делать, поэтому я его считал как положительное)

Comment: забыл я дописать конец условия: Задачу необходимо решить с помощью оператора цикла while без использования коллекций (кроме строк).

Comment: с for у меня получилось

Comment: @Антон добавил решение через while

Comment: при вводе чисел 1 и 0 выдает ошибку. Должно выводиться "EQUALS", а по этому коду получается "POSITIVE"

Comment: ну то есть, количество чисел - 1, само число - 0

Comment: @Антон ну согласно коду 0 считается положительным, могу изменить, чтоб 0 не учитывался ни в положительные ни в отрицательные

Comment: да, по-моему это верно будет

Comment: @Антон добавил изменения, теперь при вводе 1 и 0 будет выводить EQUALS

Comment: Отлично, все прошло. Благодарю!

Comment: @Антон не за что, не забудьте пометить решение как верное, чтоб ваш вопрос показывался как решенный